# Calling google assistant by a python script

Tags: python, pi-4

I'm working on raspberry pi4 which has google assistant in it. I would like to call google assistant by a python script and by sending a text command rather than a voice. Also, I would like the response to be as a sound, not text. I've tried textinut but it returns a text response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is Pi-specific? For instance, does google assistant work like you expect on a PC, but not on a Pi?

Comment: Not sure. But I'm working on raspberrypi